# What is a Sound Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

*<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>*

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a **Sound Word™**.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

[image]

For those unable to view images, here is a text version of the table:

| Sound Words™ | Not Sound Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| DECAY | DECOMPOSE |
| QUEUE | LINE |
| EIGHTY | FOURSCORE |
| ENEMY | FOE |
| EXPEDIENCY | EFFICIENCY |
| ESCAPEE | FUGITIVE |
| TEDIOUS | BORING |
| DEVIOUS | TRICKY |
| EXCELLENCY | EMINENCE |
| IVY | VINE |

Comment: are you trade marking word and phrase ?

Comment: @moonbutt74 It was how JLee did his original puzzles (see the links), and the tradition has continued. It's mostly a joke.

Comment: This exact type of word was mentioned in Vsauce's Youtube video [Dord](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb0YoRMXIY0). Michael says it's called a "gramogram" but no online dictionary has been able to define it. This might cause some trouble when you try to trademark it.

Comment: @Arc676 There are a few websites around with lists of grammagrams.  I don't think that's an "official" name; it's just something someone made up.  [Those websites](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:grammagram+-gramma) helped me in composing this puzzle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A Sound Word is a word whose every syllable sounds like a letter of the alphabet.

- Decay: DK
- Queue: Q
- Eighty: AT
- Enemy: NME
- Expediency: XPDNC
- Escapee: SKP
- Tedious: TDS
- Devious: DVS
- Excellency: XLNC
- Ivy: IV