# A word pronounced like letters

Tags: word, english, no-computers, language

Can you give me a word that when pronounced, sounds exactly like pronouncing some of the letters of the alphabet.

For example

The word TEEPEE sounds exactly like the letters T and P so TP, just as if you pronounced the two letters.

Or Ziti which sounds like ZT. Two letters pronounced.

Entity : N T T

I am looking for a word that when pronounced, uses at least 4 separate letters. All the word must be pronounced with the condition above. No partials. Special kudos to anyone who comes up with a 5 or 6 letter pronounced word. (I only have a 4 letter solution)

Please only dictionary approved words and pronunciation. No abbreviations or acronyms or proper names.

With many fine answers I will just put my solution here instead of in the answers:

> Obesity   O B C T

Comment: Note that one of your examples (ZT) is dialect-dependent, the name of the letter Z differing between American and British English.

Comment: I remember reading a book like this when I was a kid called CDB!: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDB!) [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/C-D-B-William-Steig/dp/0671666894)

Comment: Are numbers allowed by any chance?

Comment: There was some discussion about pronunciation of excellency, but entity definitely doesn't sound like N T T.

Comment: @rjpond Actually, in the UK, we pronounce the pasta "zedtee", so it still works. OK, possibly some parts of this comment don't fact-check.

Comment: Fun fact, there's a band who sorta does this with their name. Their name is INXS, but it's pronounced "in excess".

Comment: I am disappointed that the 4 letter rule disqualifies the best one of all: queue (Q)

Comment: This is pretty cool. My friends and I used to write the name of our friend Emily as "MLE". Never knew there was a name for this!

Comment: the I is pronounced differently.

Comment: I'm curious why you tagged this no computers; I'd think requiring computers would actually be a harder problem.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: Fun fact, the band Zed Zed Top also has this property.

Comment: Near-miss: *aioli*

Comment: @sgroves I've also seen REL for Ariel. One example would be 'Icon For Hire's lead singer which also has a youtube channel called 'the REL show'.

Comment: N-T-T is not a "dictionary approved" pronunciation of "entity".

Comment: Just realised because ‘The Last Jedi’ just released here - OB1KNOB (you need to stretch your mind a bit). Also I added this here because of the ’1’.

Comment: See also: [What is a Sound Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24694)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Two five-letter ones:

> Obediency and expediency (OBDNC, XPDNC)

and three 4s:

> excellency, arcadian, anemone (XLNC, RKDN, NMNE)

In general, these are called "grammagrams". There are several lists available online, including [this one](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/grammagrams) and [this questionable one](http://doncolton.com/dvs/).

Comment: The second site wouldn't happen to be your site, would it? :P

Comment: I dont know Deusovi about the list. Enemy for example. Isnt it pronounced N-E-Mee? Not N-EM-E?  Like Expediency : Isn't that pronounced X-P-D-Yun-C? Instead of XPDNC? There is a Y sound somewhere?

Comment: @DEEM Multiple syllables run together in English speech. Whether it's `/ɛn ɛm i/` or `/ɛn ɛ mi/`, the pronunciation is the same. As for the latter, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expediency) gives no `/y/` sound.

Comment: The vowel sounds in anemone are different from the one in N, I'm not sure that fits.

Comment: @DEEM That seems very based around accents. Enemy at least here is definitely can be pronounced N EM E. Same with XPDNC.

Comment: anemone is not pronounced much like NMNE

Comment: Is 'obediency' actually a word?

Comment: I still have not seen my solution which I thought was very obvious. So I will wait till I accept your answer Deusovi

Comment: @jwg Then how is it pronounced?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It is conventionally uh-nem-uh-nee not in-em-in-ee (NMNE).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone) agrees with @ZX9. The rest you mention are very good, but that first list is quite questionable as well. (E.g., "empty" is not pronounced as "em-pee-tee"; it's pronounced as "emp-tee".)

Comment: @jpmc26 - "empty" is pronounced as "MT": the `p` is often left out. And because of the blending together of syllables, the only difference is that two vowel sounds are replaced with schwas (a less significant difference than the example OP gave).

Comment: @Deusovi Yes, if you fail to enunciate, you can make more words fit into this pattern. However, I've never heard of any kind of wide recognition of a silent p in empty being the normal pronunciation.

Answer (score 12):

This probably works:

> Excellency

...pronounced as

> X-L-N-C.

Comment: Isn't it X-E-L-"e"N-C

Comment: @prog_SAHIL  X-L-N-C ~ eks-el-en-si~ excellency sounds close enough to me. I don't see where you're getting the extra 'e's from.

Comment: Dont think it is pronounced X El En C. El is pronounced more like ul I think

Comment: How you pronounce it largely depends where you are from. Personally, I think X L N C is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Does this qualify?

> [cupidity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cupidity)

Letters :

> QPDT (Although the word does not contain Q)

Comment: Not sure I'd count it, since I pronounce the second and third syllables "pih-dih", not "pee-dee"

Answer (score 1):

One 4-letter one might be

> apiary

which I think sounds sufficiently like

> A-P-R-E

though I don't find it 100% convincing because

> the R sound isn't really quite right (it's more "er" where we need "ar").

Comment: Gareth . Close but......

Comment: The question seeks "a word that when pronounced, sounds exactly like pronouncing (some of) **its own** letters" (emphasis added).  The last of your four letters doesn't fit this criterion.

Comment: That condition was edited into the question after I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

> ACIDITY

fits the bill. It can be represented as

> A-C-D-T

Comment: I pronounce that AH-SI-DI not ACD

Comment: I tend to pronounce it UH-sih-dih- which is similar to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acidity)'s `ə-ˈsi-də-`. I didn't know realize there was such variation in how this is said.

Comment: i don't really know the exact pronunciation of this one, but i find this very good ;)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if this strictly counts as a word, but there’s a poem with it and it comes many times in Wodehouse.

> Excelsior!

Which can be pronounced (probably) as

> X-L-C-R

Comment: "R" has an "ar" pronounciation to me, not "or".

Comment: First thing I thought of. There was a game called XLCR back in the day. Unlike this link google just found, the copy I had included some blurb about an "Excelsior Yu". http://bbcmicro.co.uk/game.php?id=1816

Answer (score 1):

Would you accept as a 6-letter word an extension of your 4-letter one?

> [Anti-obesity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-obesity) - as in *anti-obesity medication*.

Letters:

> NTOBCT

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decent "4-letter" word:

> Beauteous (B-U-T-S)

which can become a "6-letter" word:

> Beauteousness (B-U-T-S-N-S)

EDIT: Any reason for the downvote? Both words are on [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beauteous) and match the pronunciation of the letters as long as you say it a little quickly.

Comment: ISTM that pronouncing the last syllable of the second word as two letters (and hence, two syllables) is not justifiable, and especially not if you’re saying it quickly. Pronouncing “ous” as S is also a stretch.

Comment: @PeregrineRock For me, it sounds right when running the syllables together, but I can see it does not exactly match the dictionary pronunciation.

Comment: "beauteous" is pronounced BYOO-tee-uss, not bee-yoo-tee-ess.

Comment: Bee-yoo becomes BYOO when said together. I admit that the "ess" sound should be "us". There may also be some freedom here with regards to dialect. I still think this example is worthwhile as I believe it fits the OP's requirements more closely than some other examples.

Comment: The OP's example of entity as NTT shows there is some flexibility in pronunciation (in-tih-tee vs in-tee-tee).

Answer (score 0):

[Chris Cole's "Taxonomy of Wordplay"](http://questrel.com/#pronunciation_miscellaneous_entire_word_gramograms) lists

> elementarily (LMNTRLE)

and

> eosinophilous (ESNFLS)

as being the longest, but I find these to be unsatisfying.

Answer (score -1):

I got this one from school when I was a kid:

> XLR8 -> Accelerate

Comment: 8 is not a letter of the alphabet.